# response not return using spring rest annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

Strange issue that spring rest is not returning any response. I have tried using spring boot with `@RestController` annotation.

According to docs, it includes @ResponseBody and @controller however, on client the response is still pendin as `xhr(pending)`

I am not sure what is the issue. Looks simple but pretty bad I say.

```
@RestController
public class MyUserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity registration(@RequestBody User userBean) throws Exception {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        if (userService.isUserExist(userBean)) {
            System.out.println("user already exists");
            return new ResponseEntity(headers, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        } else {
            userService.saveUser(userBean);
            return new ResponseEntity(headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

Client side javascript(node js) to send ajax request:

```
var express = require('express');

app.post('/registration', registration);

function registration(req, res, next){
    request({
        url:'http://localhost:8084/RootScopeIT_Riot/registration',
        method:'POST',
        json: {
            "username": req.body.username, "password": req.body.password
        },
        function(error, response, body){
            if(error){
                console.log('err while registration');
                return res.send(error);
            }else{
                console.log('success registration');
                return res.send({body});
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What does your `User` bean look like? Do the field names match to result in a valid `RequestBody`?

Comment: @DanielBubenheim fixed it just now. Thanks

Comment: Good to hear. What was the problem at the end?

Comment: @DanielBubenheim It was nodejs `request` library that caused the issue

Comment: Ok. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do `return` of `res.send`. Just remove `return` statement and let me know if that works.

Comment: but the `console.log('success registration');` is not printing at all

Comment: anyway i will change it and let you know

Comment: Do you have any debugger on the server?

Comment: but even after debugging there are no errors i can see